# Lync API: Unable to get all contact endpoints (for my own endpoints)

Tags: c#, api, lync

I have problem getting all contact endpoints using the Lync API. Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
  var endpoints = (List<object>)client.Self.Contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints);
}
```

Here's my Lync setup:

[image]

However when I debug, I only get two endpoints:

[image]

Is this a bug in the API? Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer to this question: [Lync - inconsistent behavior with ContactEndpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516690/lync-inconsistent-behavior-with-contactendpoints)

You may find that this answer from Microsoft is the answer to your issue as well:

> The behavior you are seeing is due to presence subscription
>   optimization to the Lync client so that the subscription is delayed
>   until the necessary contact information is required by the Lync
>   client. Photo is an example for this optimization. Another example is
>   ContactEndpoints. Please take a look at [Contact presence subscription
>   changes section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/jj933253.aspx) of the Migration doc for Lync 2013 page in MSDN
>   docs. Specifically you must create and maintain your own
>   ContactSubscription for the contacts that you need all the
>   ContactEndpoints.

Comment: I am aware of this (I guess this was a change for the Lync 2013 API). In the examples explaining this - Presence information is shown. I do not believe that this is the root cause for not getting all of my own endpoints. And this is for the Self contact.

Comment: Did you try writing your own ContactSubscription for Self just to be sure?

Comment: There is no ContactSubscription method on Self, there is a BeginPublishContactInformation method - is that the one?